# Alternative to JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes in .NET Standard

Tags: c#, .net-standard

JsonSerializer is part of System.Text.Json namespace of .NET Core & .NET 5. Unfortunately it's unavailable in .NET Standard.

Is there any alternative to JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes method available in .NET Standard?

Comment: Why you need this? what is stopping you from using other library, serialize to string and get UTF8 bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be alternative:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message))
```

Comment: `JsonConvert` requires the Newtonsoft package from NuGet.  I would suggest installing Newtonsoft and using the code here.

Comment: This is bad suggestion.... I debated to downvote it... but since many other answers suggest the same pointless approach it sounds like this is favored by people... Indeed this is duplicate answer... Really no point of getting string result if one needs Utf8 output in a stream/byte array.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov with given "standard" libraries(yes, I know `Newtonsoft.Json` is not standard but before `System.Text.Json` even MS use it in ASP.NET core) there is no way to write directly into `UTF8`  using .NET Standard 2.1 ... this makes question pointless( the answer is: you cannot) or makes it off-topic (as prolly you would find library which can do this, but asking for library is off-topic) ... so this is alternative but with downside (at least 3x memory usage and obviously CPU)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Newtonsoft package from NuGet to serialize into a string (`JsonConvert.SerializeObject`).  Then use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` to encode the string to a byte array using UTF8.

The reason there are 2 calls is separation of concerns. Serialization and encoding are 2 separate concerns which should not be combined, at least not at the package level.

You are free to write a helper method in your app that combines them of course... one method to turn an object into a UTF-8 encoded byte array.  But first make sure that a byte array is really required.  In my experience that is rare.  Usually you can work directly with the serialized string.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, apparently since .NET 6 [`SerializeToUtf8Bytes` is available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serializetoutf8bytes?view=net-6.0) in `System.Text.Json`.
So you don't need to use Newtonsoft for that.